# Wolfram workbench syntax highlighting for local variables inside compile

Tags: workbench, syntax-highlighting

Lately I've been working quite a lot with `Compile`. I also started using Wolfram Workbench.

So a natural question arises: Is it possible to have syntax highlighting for  local variable variables inside compile as well? Here is a screenshot demonstrating the problem. Notice the blue `x`'s in the lower right hand side of the image? These should be green.

[image: Screenshot]

I didn't manage to find anything under the preferences. I'm using WB 2.0

Comment: Someone from WRI has to answer/fix this. In the meanwhile I would just use a simple trick and put a Block around, e.g.:
cf = Block[ {x},
         Compile[{{x, _Real}}, Sin[x] + x^2 - 1/(1 + x)]
     ]

Comment: @RolfMertig That's actually not a bad idea. Does this have any performance or any other side effects?

Comment: no, it just evaluates to its body, so all is good.

Comment: @RolfMertig Could you put that as an answer? I think this is what I'll end up doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Until (when, WRI??) there will be an update of WWB (which certainly will also fix other shortcomings and bugs) just use Block to get the coloring right:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, you cannot change this. I cannot exactly say how it works in Eclipse, but usually the highlighting process consists of several steps. Basic highlighting can be provided after the lexical analysis. For a context sensitive highlighting like the one for local variables inside `Module`, `Block`, `Function` or in your case `Compile`, you need to parse the input.

If you are using the Workbench *plugin* for Eclipse, you can at least get an idea where and how this is implemented. In the `plugins` directory (in OSX) inside your Eclipse installation path you should find directories for the Wolfram plugin. If you dig a bit in the `lib` directory there, you'll find that an `antlr` parser was created to parse *Mathematica* code. With the help of this parser highlighting and error/warning features are implemented and provided for Eclipse inside the `MEET.jar`.

To change the behaviour for `Compile`, you would have to change it inside the MEET code which you don't have access to since the `jar` files contain (almost) only byte-code.

Comment: Yes, I did manage to get that far and even got a look inside using http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui, but then I got totally lost...